# C: Extracting two floats that are in string

Tags: c, string

First of all sorry for my english....

I have a string that's like strng=(x=Number1,y=Number2) and I want to extract both Number1 and Number2 in two differente variables. 
I have extracted the string from a file, and I can't change the file : It has been given by our teacher and I highly doubt he'll like it if I change it to make everything easier.

I'm doing it on CodeBlocks. I've tried to use a sscanf but I can't make it work. I've also try to use strtok but I struggle to understand how it work.sscanf seemed like a good idea to me, but while there's no error message, it doesn't work.

```
fscanf(file,"%s",string[i].coordonee); // string[i].coordonee=(x=13.5, y=34.6)
sscanf(string[i].coordonee," (x=%lf, y=%lf)",&Nbx,&Nby);
```

There's no error message, but I've tried to print Nbx and Nby and it's 0. 
My goal is, with the example I provided, to get Nbx=13.5 and Nby=34.6.

Thank you !

Comment: Use `fgets` instead of `fscanf`.

Comment: If you print out `string[i].coordonee` before the `sscanf` call, what do you get?

Comment: `sscanf` is probably a good tool for this job.  But you *must* check its return value.  If `sscanf` returns anything other than 2, something has gone wrong, and one or both conversions did not succeed.

Comment: @SteveSummit It prints (x=13.5, y=34.6), so at least this is right

Comment: Are you sure? Are you really using `scanf`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't think I can; I've simplified everything but in reality I have more informations in my file, just not those two points

Comment: Then please provide [mcve]. From the lines you are showing you can't get the output you are claiming you get.

Comment: What are the types of `Nbx` and `Nby`?  If they're `float`, change `%lf` in your `sscanf` format string to `%f`.

Comment: Don't forget to check the return value of `sscanf`. C won't show you an error message automatically, you have to explicitly check for an error. Scanf returns the number of successfully parsed elements. In your case, if it is smaller than 2, than there's some error.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to just use fscanf to read values from file. If it's needed to read string string first then it's better to use fgets as it will read entire line or number of chars specified which ever comes first.

For strtok, in first call you need to pass buffer and list of delimiters, then pass null to continue tokenization.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {  

    // Using fscanf
    {
        double x, y;
        FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
        int count = fscanf(fp,"(x=%lf, y=%lf)",&x, &y);
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Result: %lf, %lf, values read: %d \n", x, y, count);
    }

    // Using sscanf and fgets
    {
        double x, y;
        FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
        char buffer[500];
        fgets(buffer, 500, fp);
        fclose(fp);
        int count = sscanf(buffer,"(x=%lf, y=%lf)",&x,&y);
        printf("Result: %lf, %lf, values read: %d\n", x, y, count);
    } 

    // Using strtok
    {
        double x, y;
        FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
        char buffer[500];
        fgets(buffer, 500, fp);
        fclose(fp);

        char *name1  = strtok (buffer, "(, =)");
        char *value1 = strtok (NULL, "(, =)");
        char *name2  = strtok (NULL, "(, =)");
        char *value2 = strtok (NULL, "(, =)");

        printf("Result: %s = %s, %s = %s\n", name1, value1, name2, value2);
    } 
}
```